# Programming assignment month's of the year

Tags: java, substring, variable-assignment

I am training in some programming exercises and this one kept me busy for a long while. It says the following:

Your job is to transform numbers 1,2,3,...,12 into the corresponding month names January, February, March, ... , December. Implement a class Month whose constructor parameter is the month number and whose getName method returns the months name. Hint: Make a very long string "January February March ...", in which you add spaces such that each month name has the same length. Then use substring to extract the month you want.

Unfortunately I made not every month the same amount of spaces but that shouldn't be a problem  if i thought the numbers through.

For now i have not used a switch statement. I will learn about it in the near future. The thing which makes this assignment a little tricky is that i cannot use arrays, switches, if/for loops. Keep in mind that i must follow the tips in the text. I cannot simply use literals but need to make 1 large string and return substrings with the month.

The problem is: how do I connect a number to a specific substring? Help appreciated!

This is my code:

```
public class Month
{
private int number;
private String month;

public Month(int theNumber)
{
    number = theNumber;
}

public String getName()
{
    String month = "January February March April May June July August September October November December";
    String january = month.substring(0,7);//January
    String february = month.substring(8,16);//February
    String march = month.substring(17,22);//March
    String april = month.substring(23,28);//April
    String may = month.substring(29,32);//May
    String june = month.substring(33,37);//June
    String july = month.substring(38,42);//July
    String august = month.substring(43,49);//August
    String september = month.substring(50,59);//September
    String october = month.substring(60,67);//October
    String november = month.substring(68,76);//November
    String december = month.substring(77,84);//December        
    return month;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the same amount of letters of the month plus the spaces you can do the following:

1. Look for the longest name of the month.
2. Fill all other names of the months with spaces to have the same amount of letters.
   The month with the most letters is September. Which has 9 letters
3. Use substring with the given number of the month like:

   ```
   number = 0 = January
   number = 1 = February
   number = 11 = December
   ```

Then you can extract your name of the month from the String with this:

```
substring(number*9, number*9+9)
```

Comment: You need to `trim()` the result in order to discard the white spaces.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Right, there are some more problems. But I think for this excercise it's good enough to get the basic idea. Because it will be an output on the console anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String getName(int m) {

    if(m < 1 || m > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month number.");
    }

    String months[] = {"January","February","March","April","May",
        "June","July","August","September","November","December"}

    return months[m-1];
}
```

Rather than a big long String and trying to pull substrings out of it, I suggest a String array, with each index being the string representing the month name.

The main problem with your original method is that you're not taking in an argument to tell you which month name should be returned.  The code I've posted has modified your `getName()` method to now ask for an `int` representing the number of the month, and should return a String representing the name of that month.

For example, `"January"` is at index `0` of the `months` array.  So `getName(1)` will return `"January"`.

---

EDIT: Noting user1274223's answer... I'd recommend this actually...

Since your class is named `Month` and the methods are non-static, we'll assume each instantiation of the class represents a singular month.  In which case, I'd modified two of your methods...

First, your `getName()` method can simply look like this:

```
public String getName() {
    return month;
}
```

But now you should be modifying your constructor.

```
public Month(int m) {
    number = m;
    month = // logic to set the value of the string variable month, whether you use my array or a switch or whatever
}
```

And really, ideally, your `Month(int m)` constructor should just call a `setter` that both sets `number` and `month` in the same method call.  Get that logic straight in that `setter`, and then call that setter any time you need set/change the month number/name.  This will keep both the number and name of the month in sync (which should be done).

The point here really though is that your `getName()` method should be no more than `return month;` and `month` should be set and maintained elsewhere in this class.

NOTE: As one final, final note... if you really, really must use substrings (and I'm not going to write that code because in this instance it's really impractical and only useful for doing homework...) I'd count to the `nth` capital letter and return the substring from that index to the index of the first space character following it.

It's easy to differentiate capitals and lowercase letters, and none of the months have spaces within them.  It's a space-delimited index of month names.

Think of it as "J F M A M J J A S N D".  Want month 8?  "J F M A M J J A".  You found the 8th capital letter, which will have whatever index.  So return the characters between that index and the index of the first space you find after that character.  In this case, you'd return "August".

Comment: I appreciate the answer but the thing is: i have yet not encountered the 'switch' statement. I know how to make an array or arraylist i am not allowed to use these methods. Do you know another method for coupling an integer to a specific substring?

Comment: This answer is a very elegant solution, @@user3111770.learn the switch statement, its very helpful. Or look at the answer I suggested with the HashMap

Comment: @user3111770 I've updated the answer a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you store the month names in separate objects (strings), there is no need for the line:

```
    String month = "January February March April May June July August September October November December";
```

To return a month name just use a switch statement:{

```
switch(number){
case 1: return january;
case 2: return february;
//etc
default : throw new RuntimeException("Invalid month number: " + number);
}
```

EDIT: As `nhgrif` suggested you can simply return string literals : `return "January"`

EDIT2: You can use constant number of chars for each month name:
`String months = "January|||February|||..."` where `|` is sapace, so that  all names have equal length.  Then to get a month name you can use:

`String name = months.substring(number*nameLength, number*nameLength + nameLength).trim();`

Comment: Rather than creating 12 String objects then returning one of them, why not just return literals?  `case 1: return "January";` etc.

Comment: He can, I just tried to stay as close as possible to his code.

Comment: For now i have not used a switch statement. I will learn about it in the near future. The thing it makes this assignment a little tricky is that i cannot use arrays, switches, if/for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Since the methods of the class are not static, I'm assuming you have instances of each `Month`, which you supply as a constructor parameter, the number of each month.

If you haven't learned about the Java `HashMap` class, it would be a great place to start. I encourage you to learn how to use it and how it works.

In essence, a `HashMap` maps key/value pairs. You can think of it as a dictionary. Each word is a key and the value associated with it is the definition. For example, the word 'computer' is a key into the dictionary, and the value associated with it is the definition of the word 'computer'.

With this in mind, a design for the `Month` class could be to have a `static HashMap` that is pre-loaded with key/value pairs, such as 1 = 'January', 2 = 'February', so on and so forth.

getName() would then just retrieve the stored map value according the month number that was passed in the constructor.

For example:

```
public String getName()
{

       return hashMap.get(number);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Month {
    private static final String ALLMONTHS = "January February March April May June July August September October November December";
    private String myMonth;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Month
 */
public Month(int monthNumber) {
    switch(monthNumber) {
    case 1: myMonth = ALLMONTHS.substring(0,7); break;
    case 2: myMonth = ALLMONTHS..substring(8,16); break;
    //
    //  Continue cases 3,4,5...default
    //
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return myMonth;
}
```

}

What I used was a single static string for all the months, in the constructor use a switch to assign the `myMonth` string, and then your `getName()` just returns the `myMonth` string.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep in mind that i am doing an assignment in chapter 3 in which arrays, if/for loops are not allowed.

If arrays, conditions (if, switch/case) aren't allowed, probably the fixed length of the months are required after all: With a little bit of math you can calculate the parameters (start end end index) for substring.